# O que é e como eu posso utilizar o 'extends' e 'abstract' em um public main?

Tags: java, classes

Oi, sou iniciante na área de programação e atualmente estou aprendendo no curso de desenvolvimento de jogos.
O professor do curso não conseguiu deixar claro para mim o que é e como usar o extends e o abstract, assisti o módulo inteiro de orientação de objetos em java 3 vezes e não consegui absorver nada sobre isso.
Se algum expert conseguir me ajudar com isso explicando da forma mais burra para mim eu agradeço :D

```
public class Main extends(Exemplo){}

public abstract class Main{}
```

Comment: Khallzone evite citar ou referenciar marcas, a não ser que seja relevante para o conteúdo, pois é considerado prática de span.

Comment: erro meu xD na próxima eu fico de bico fechado kk

Comment: Eu fiz a edição e adicionei a tag `java` a pergunta.

Comment: No fundo a pergunta é ampla porque envolve dois conceitos, marquei um deles, o outro eu acho que é melhor olhar na *tag* que tem diversas respostas sobre isto https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/heran%c3%a7a?tab=Votes. Fora isto é complicado porque não sabemos o que viu, porque não entendeu, qual é o ponto específico, se está preparado para entender esse conceito, qualquer resposta pode ser inútil, a pergunta não tem especificidade alguma.